# Magmi: missing products

Tags: magento, csv, import, magmi

Whenever I do an import with Magmi, it misses products without telling me what happened.
For example on this screenshot below, you can see it found 226 records but only imported 194 items.
[image]
What happened to the remaining 32 items? Can I find their SKU? Why weren't they imported? Is there any place I can find this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely had some values in the products that halter their import or they contained data that broke the import.

Do the following:

Check

```
SELECT sku 
FROM catalog_product_entity 
ORDER BY entity_id
WHERE
sku
IN
(
.. list of skus you're importing commas separated.
)
```

To get the skus that you've successfully imported.

Set **Magmi import delimiter** to | (pipe) and use **open office** when saving csv files and force them to have quotes around each field and be pipe separated **to avoid any and all quote and comma issues** within your data.

Comment: I used the pipe delimiter and wrote my csv with fwrite instead of using fputcsv in order to have more control. That helped getting rid of a lot of import failures.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable and configure Magmi report mail notifier. Every time you import products you will receive a report containing the information about the successfully imported and failed to import products skus.To receive the email you need to configure your email id.